# Comparing strings in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
NSString *title = [myWebView 
                   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];  
int j = 0;
int i=0;
int count=0;   
int len;
len = [title length];

for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    NSString *c = [title substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

    if([c isEqualToString:@","])
    {
        //array[count]= [title substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, 2)];
        NSString *xxx = [title substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j,(i-j))];
        NSLog(xxx);

        //insert the string into array
        [array insertObject:xxx atIndex:count];
        j=i;
        count = count + 1;
    }

}
```

My app always crashes at the line

```
[c isEqualToString:@","]
```

and gives the error - Thread1 : Program received signal: "SIGBART".

I know for sure that the problem is occurring while comparing strings since the app runs if  I remove that one line of code.

Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: The only way for the app to crash on the isEqualToString line is that the `c` variable was somehow released. Is your sample code unedited ? Maybe you could try to enable zombie debugging for your application : http://cocoaforbreakfast.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/exc_bad_access-a-zombie-nightmare/

Comment: Also, if your `NSRange` is invalid, you can get a `NSRangeException`. Are you sure there is none?

Comment: int i = 0; Right after I declared NSString *title

Comment: What other intervening code have you left out then? :)

Comment: edited the question. now it has all the source code

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you are creating an array why not use [title componentsSeparatedByString:@","]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

Example:

```
NSString *title = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
NSMutableArray *array = [title componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: It crashes at the line you mentioned. It printed this line before crashing - [Switching to process 2307 thread 0x207]
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: I also tried running the NSZombie and didn't discover anything out there :(

Comment: Perhaps `title` is not a valid string.

Comment: NSLog(title) prints out the following line - "part1","part2",number,"11/11/2011","part3","4567.21",4423322

Comment: I think CocoaFu is on the right track. Maybe the webview returns some strange subclass of NSString that causes the problem. Try `NSLog("Class: %@",[title class]);`. Maybe you can circumvent the problem using something like `title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", title]`. Or just use `-isEqual:` rather than `isEqualToString:`

Comment: @Ashish if the above is what `NSLog` prints then it is not an `NSString`. An NSString would print it's entire contents within a single set of quotes.  The above looks like a `NSLog` of an array, it would be easier if the entire NELog statement was provided, perhaps it is surrounded by parens or braces?  Always go for the simplest test when things are failing.

Comment: You were right. the string title had a bunch of double quotes which were messing up everything.

Answer (score 0):

If I ends up longer than the string, or is undefined, you've got issues. If you replace i with 1, it doesn't crash, right?

Incidentally, you could use:

```
unichar c = [title characterAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: It still crashed at the same line

Comment: if `c` were NULL, (or rather `nil` since it is an Obj-C object), then the expression would immediately evaluate to 0. In Objective C it is allowed to send messages to nil.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", c); just before the crash line and tell us the output?

Comment: Good points, reckless me. Answer edited to focus on the point I was trying to make (still apparently incorrectly).

Comment: It printed all the characters of NSString *title (one in each line)